# App only available on iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ipad

I uploaded my application how I normally do it -- built using phonegap/cordova and exporting my build from xcode to build.phonegap.com.

My app got approved on iTunes and I went to try and download it on my iPhone 6 but got a message that it is only available for iPad only even though it says "this app is designed for both iPhone and iPad" in the iTunes store. Is this a bug or what can be done to fix this glitch? Help appreciated, thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had this once when my app was fresh on iTunes, it went back to normal after a while. How long has it been available?

Comment: 24 hours, I realized it wasn't available in the USA and checked the mark and tried to search for it a few hours later. Thank you for this I'll check back later.